# Geoserver WFS-T "Feature type 'Workspace:Layer' is not available" Error on update / delete

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, update, wfs-t

I am using the following code for insert / update (changed from this source: https://medium.com/@goldrydigital/wfs-t-with-openlayers-3-16-6fb6a820ac58):

```
var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();

// GML Format zur Interaktion mit WFS
var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
  featureNS: 'http://my-address:8080/geoserver/web/myworkspace',
  featureType: 'MyWorkspace:MyLayer',
  srsName: myProjectionName
});

var transactWFS = function(transactionType,feature) {
  var node;
  switch(transactionType) {
    case 'insert':
      node = formatWFS.writeTransaction([feature],null,null,formatGML);
    break;
    case 'update':
      node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null,[feature],null,formatGML);
      break;
    case 'delete':
      node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null,null,[feature],formatGML);
      break;
  }
  s = new XMLSerializer();
  str = s.serializeToString(node);

  // XMLHttpRequest
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = 'http://my-address:8080/geoserver/web/myworkspace/wfs';
  xhttp.open('POST', url, true);
  //xhttp.setRequestHeader('crossDomain', true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('dataType', 'xml');
  //xhttp.setRequestHeader('processData', false);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('contentType', 'text/xml');
  //xhttp.onreadystatechange = handler;
  xhttp.send(str);
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log("Request Response: " + xhttp.responseText);
  };
}
```

The insert works like it should using this function:

```
// Button to add a Feature
$("#btn_add").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // create feature from draw feature
    var feature = drawSource.getFeatures()[0];
    // set properties
    feature.setProperties({
      NAME: $("#name").val(),
      AGE: $("#age").val(),
      GEOLOC: feature.getGeometry()
    });
    // Insert feature
    transactWFS('insert', feature);
});
```

For update I am using this functions (taking values from text field like in the insert function and not changing the geometry):

```
// Button to change a Feature
$("#btn_change").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // get selected feature from map (selectedFeature)
  var feature = selectedFeature;
  feature.setProperties({
      NAME: $("#name").val(),
      AGE: $("#age").val()
  });
  // update feature
  transactWFS('update', feature);
});
```

The update function is throwing this exception

```
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
  <ows:ExceptionText>Feature type 'MyWorkspace:MyLayer' is not available: </ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
```

The feature type is not changed so I do not know why the insert is working but the update is not.

The "geoserver.log" Error Information (DEBUG level):

> 2015-12-01 11:36:22,184 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
>   Request: getServiceInfo
>   2015-12-01 11:36:22,200 DEBUG [geotools.xml] - schemaLocation found: http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd
>   2015-12-01 11:36:22,200 DEBUG [geotools.xml] - Found override for http://www.opengis.net/wfs: http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd ==> jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%208.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-wfs-2.8.0.jar!/org/geoserver/wfs/xml/v1_1_0/wfs.xsd
>   2015-12-01 11:36:22,200 DEBUG [geoserver.wfs] - Locating FeatureSource uri:'http://my-address:8080/geoserver/web/myworkspace' name:'MyWorkspace:MyLayer'
>   2015-12-01 11:36:22,200 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
>   org.geoserver.wfs.WFSTransactionException: Feature type 'MyWorkspace:MyLayer' is not available: 
>       at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction.execute(Transaction.java:221)
>       at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction.transaction(Transaction.java:106)
>       at org.geoserver.wfs.DefaultWebFeatureService.transaction(DefaultWebFeatureService.java:171)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor577.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>       at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:55)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.transaction(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor576.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:845)
>       at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:275)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
>       at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
>       at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
>       at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:83)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
>       at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
>       at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:135)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2503)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2492)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   2015-12-01 11:36:22,200 DEBUG [geoserver.filters] - Compressing output for mimetype: application/xml
>   2015-12-01 11:36:22,200 DEBUG [filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed

And the input log to compare:

> 2015-12-01 11:43:58,111 DEBUG [geotools.xml] - schemaLocation found: http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd
>   2015-12-01 11:43:58,111 DEBUG [geotools.xml] - Found override for http://www.opengis.net/wfs: http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd ==> jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%208.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-wfs-2.8.0.jar!/org/geoserver/wfs/xml/v1_1_0/wfs.xsd
>   2015-12-01 11:43:58,111 DEBUG [geotools.xml] - Could not find declaration for: {http://my-address:8080/geoserver/web/myworkspace}geometry. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
>   2015-12-01 11:43:58,111 DEBUG [geotools.xml] - Could not find declaration for: {http://my-address:8080/geoserver/web/myworkspace}geometry. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
>   2015-12-01 11:43:58,111 DEBUG [geotools.xml] - Could not find declaration for: {http://my-address:8080/geoserver/web/myworkspace}geometry. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
>   2015-12-01 11:43:58,126 DEBUG [geoserver.wfs] - Locating FeatureSource uri:'http://my-address:8080/geoserver/web/myworkspace' name:'MyLayer'
>   2015-12-01 11:43:58,126 DEBUG [geoserver.wfs] - located FeatureType w/ typeRef 'ORACLE MYDATASTORE:MyLayer' and elementName '{http://my-address:8080/geoserver/web/myworkspace}MyLayer'
>   2015-12-01 11:43:58,126 DEBUG [geoserver.wfs] - Transasction Insert:org.geoserver.wfs.request.Insert$WFS11@60401ca0
>   2015-12-01 11:43:58,126 TRACE [geotools.factory] - ENTRY  (CoordinateOperationFactory, COORDINATE_OPERATION_FACTORY)
>   2015-12-01 11:43:58,126 TRACE [geotools.factory] - RETURN (CoordinateOperationFactory, COORDINATE_OPERATION_FACTORY): found implementation BufferedCoordinateOperationFactory.
>   2015-12-01 11:43:58,126 DEBUG [geoserver.wfs] - Use featureValidation to check contents of insert

Comment: are you sure the insert works or does it just not display an error? what is the datastore you are using on GeoServer? what does the DEBUG level log file say when it fails.

Comment: Yes I am sure the insert works properly. I am using an Oracle Database("Oracle NG  - Oracle Database"). Where do I find this DEBUG level log? I attached the "geoserver.log" error to my question.

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level in the global settings page - then you will see the actual XML received by GeoServer in the log.

Comment: I changed the logging level to DEBUG and attached the Input log for comparison.

Comment: Figured it out: The featureType had to be set like this:
`featureType: 'MyLayer'`
and not to "MyWorkspace:MyLayer"!
The DEBUG log helped though. Tank you.

Comment: can you plesae share your code

Comment: @user28536 I answered the question below (including the code)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an error in the GML Format featureType Parameter:

```
var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
  featureNS: 'http://my-address:8080/geoserver/web/myworkspace',
  featureType: 'MyLayer',
  srsName: myProjectionName
});
```

The featureType just needs the layername and not the "Workspace:LayerName"-format!